# The const signInWithGoogle isn't being exported in react and the screen becomes white because of it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm using react and firebase and trying to implement signing in with google, but the viewport becomes white probably because the function is not being exported from utils file. Because when I delete it from login.js, the components are displayed

This is my code in utils.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/auth'
import {firebaseConfig} from './config'

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)


export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();

const GoogleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
GoogleProvider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' });

export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(GoogleProvider);
export default signInWithGoogle
```

And this is my Login.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './Login.scss'
import Buttons from '../Buttons'
import { signInWithGoogle }  from '../../firebase/utils'


class Login extends Component {

  handleSubmit = async e => {
     e.preventDefault();
}
render() {

return (
    <div className='login'>
        <div className='login_wrapper'>
            <h3 className='login_heading'>Login</h3>
            <form className='login_form' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <Buttons onClick={signInWithGoogle}>
                    <div className='button_name'>
                        Sign in with Google
                    </div>
                </Buttons>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
)
 }
 }
 export default Login
```

I also tried to write like this

```
 let signInWithGoogle;
 export default signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(GoogleProvider)
```

But the console says that signInWithGoogle is not exported from utils.js

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is caused by your `signInWithGoogle` method returning a `Promise` object which is blocking your component.

You can either change

```js
export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(GoogleProvider);
```

to (this isn't recommended, as it makes error handling harder)

```
export const signInWithGoogle = () => { auth.signInWithPopup(GoogleProvider) };
```

or change how you use it in your component:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Login.scss";
import Buttons from "../Buttons";
import { signInWithGoogle } from "../../firebase/utils";

class Login extends Component {
  handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  
  render() {
    const onClickSignInWithGoogle = () => {
      signInWithGoogle() // doesn't return the Promise
        .catch((err) => { // don't forget error handling
          console.error("Sign in failed!", err);
          alert("Failed to sign in!");
        });
    }
    
    return (
      <div className="login">
        <div className="login_wrapper">
          <h3 className="login_heading">Login</h3>
          <form className="login_form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <Buttons onClick={onClickSignInWithGoogle}>
              <div className="button_name">Sign in with Google</div>
            </Buttons>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Login;
```

Comment: Thank you! But I just realised that I didn't export the config file, which caused the problem. Such a dumb mistake